# Why I do not have ſ in XeTeX/fontspec?

Tags: xetex, fontspec, ligatures

I am trying to get the ligatures with long s, the `ſ` with Cormorant Garamond but this does not appear...

My code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont[Extension={.ttf}, BoldFont={CormorantGaramond-Bold_0}, ItalicFont={CormorantGaramond-Italic_0}, Ligatures={TeX,Rare,Historic, Required, Contextual,  Common}, Contextuals=Inner]{CormorantGaramond-Regular_1}

\begin{document}

Islam aspice astice lactosio asfissia stort ctore fb ffi fi fp sk sp ss  Qu Qw


\end{document}
```

My output:

[image]

A note: At the .ttf file I noticed the name .ss02 on the ligates of the type `ſ`, I tried StylisticSet=2, but did not work too.

Comment: `medi`, `clig`, and `rlig` features aren’t found in Cormorant Garamond, so selecting `Ligatures={Required,Contextual}` and `Contextuals=Inner` does nothing. No feature controlling ‘ſ’ automatically has been defined, so you’ll have to type it directly (in luatex, you could define a feature on the fly, but it would be complicated to do correctly).

Comment: @Thérèse Yes... Thhi is terrible, unfortunately...

Comment: It *would* be terrible in long texts, but the Cormorant fonts were designed for display, and the manual interventions required aren’t very burdensome in short, display texts.

Answer (score 5):

To obtain the font go here: https://github.com/CatharsisFonts/Cormorant/releases (it's free)

I don't know how to do it in XeTeX, but in LuaTeX you can make those ligatures available with a little bit of Lua code.  I guess that is also the reason why you cannot easily access them otherwise.  All the slots have a `.liga` attached to their name.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\directlua{
```

```lua
fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature({
    name = "liga",
    type = "ligature",
    data = {
        ['longs_b.liga'] = { "s", "b" },
        ['longs_h.liga'] = { "s", "h" },
        ['longs_i.liga'] = { "s", "i" },
        ['longs_j.liga'] = { "s", "j" },
        ['longs_k.liga'] = { "s", "k" },
        ['longs_l.liga'] = { "s", "l" },
        ['longs_longs.liga'] = { "s", "s" },
        ['longs_longs_b.liga'] = { "s", "s", "b" },
        ['longs_longs_h.liga'] = { "s", "s", "h" },
        ['longs_longs_i.liga'] = { "s", "s", "i" },
        ['longs_longs_j.liga'] = { "s", "s", "j" },
        ['longs_longs_k.liga'] = { "s", "s", "k" },
        ['longs_longs_l.liga'] = { "s", "s", "l" },
    }
})
```

```
}

\setmainfont[Ligatures={Rare,Historic}]{Cormorant-Regular.otf}

\begin{document}
Islam aspice astice lactosio asfissia stort ctore fb ffi fi fp sk sp ss  Qu Qw
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry for the delay, but thanks for your answer, maybe I consider change to LuaLateX :)

Comment: @Gergian If you don't need bidirectional typesetting or complex scripts (like Devanagari or Arabic), there is no reason not to switch to LuaTeX, especially because math typesetting is much more robust in LuaTeX.