# Fraktur (blackletter) typesetting with certain automated features?

Tags: luatex

This question is somewhat related to [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/60360/3925).

Background: I have a book from 1855 (Faust) of which I'd like to create a kind of facsimile version. At this point it isn't too important to make sure to have the exact font reproduced as the *style*. So for my purposes and for an initial version I am settling for UnifrakturMaguntia for now. However, maybe I'll also test with `yfonts` and so on.

However, one goal would be to be able to toggle between using a Fraktur (blackletter) typeface and contemporary typefaces with serifs (keep that in mind while reading the remainder of this question).

Given the nature of the old 19th century blackletter typesetting, I am concerned about the following items:

- How to properly typeset long ſ versus round s?

  - This is kind of a biggie actually, because preferably I'd like to type away in my editor and not have to care at which point a long ſ is called for and at what point it should be a round s. Can LuaLaTeX be employed to help in this without actually having to change how I type the text?
- Since the text is pre-1880 it doesn't follow the (German) spelling rules established by the [Duden](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duden). This means any automatic features such as hyphenation aren't going to work reliably (I reckon). It's not as much of an issue for this type of text, but I am eyeing at creating a facsimile of sorts of another body of text with similar requirements in the future.

[This answer by Håkon Malmedal](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60548/3925) addresses how to use `\emph` to use wide letter spacing for emphasis. But neither answer on said question has an automated version of long ſ versus round s.

Consider the following sample from aforementioned book.

```
\documentclass[paper=A6]{scrbook}
%\usepackage{yfonts}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainfont{UnifrakturMaguntia}
\renewcommand\emshape{\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=20.0,Ligatures=Required,Ligatures=NoCommon}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
        {\Huge Faust.}\vspace{4ex}

        Eine Tragödie\vspace{4ex}

        {\tiny von}\vspace{4ex}

        {\Large \bfseries Goethe.}\vspace{4ex}

        {\small Beide Theile in Einem Bande.}\vspace{4ex}

        \rule{5em}{.5pt}\vspace{4ex}

        {\bfseries Stuttgart und Augsburg.}

        \emph{J. G. Cotta'ſcher Verlag.}

        1855.
    \end{center}

\pagebreak

    \begin{center}
    \emph{\large \bfseries Der Tragödie}

    \emph{erster Theil.}

    {\footnotesize Nacht.}

    {\bfseries Faust}

    {\scriptsize (in einem hochgewölbten, engen, gothischen Zimmer unruhig auf seinem Sessel am Pulte).}
    \end{center}

    Habe nun, ach! Philosophie,

    Juristerei und Medicin,

    Und, leider! auch Theologie

    Durchaus studirt, mit heißem Bemühn.

    Da steh' ich nun, ich armer Thor!

    Und bin so klug, als wie zuvor;

    Heiße Magister, heiße Doctor gar,

    Und ziehe schon an die zehen Jahr,

    Herauf, herab, und quer und krumm,

    Meine Schüler an der Nase herum ---

    ...
\end{document}
```

Now on page one I have used the long ſ in "J. G. Cotta'ſcher Verlag.", ..

[image: page one, explicit use of long ſ]

... but on page two I haven't used the long ſ *explicitly* anywhere and the outcome is not what's desired:

[image: page two, no explicit use of long ſ]

Instead I would hope to automatically get the outcome I get from *explicitly* setting the long ſ (second page adjusted accordingly):

```
\begin{center}
\emph{\large \bfseries Der Tragödie}

\emph{erſter Theil.}

{\footnotesize Nacht.}

{\bfseries Fauſt}

{\scriptsize (in einem hochgewölbten, engen, gothiſchen Zimmer unruhig auf ſeinem Seſſel am Pulte).}
\end{center}

Habe nun, ach! Philoſophie,

Juriſterei und Medicin,

Und, leider! auch Theologie

Durchaus ſtudirt, mit heißem Bemühn.

Da ſteh' ich nun, ich armer Thor!

Und bin ſo klug, als wie zuvor;

Heiße Magiſter, heiße Doctor gar,

Und ziehe ſchon an die zehen Jahr,

Herauf, herab, und quer und krumm,

Meine Schüler an der Naſe herum ---

...
```

[image: page 2 with explicit long ſ to demonstrate the desired result]

Now, this is still just an approximation of the real book (font doesn't match 100% and some lines are broken differently), but I want to hash out the details before I proceed.

Here's a sample of the real thing (what's page 2 in the above example):

[image: an excerpt from the original representing approximately page 2 from above]

**TL;DR:** How can I automate the use of long ſ versus round s without having to explicitly type the long ſ all the time. Preferred engine LuaTeX.

**NB:** if you can recommend a closer match to the font shown in the above photo, I'd be glad if you'd point it out (be it in a comment or answer). Thanks.

PS: I am literate in vanilla Lua, but not necessarily in the ways it's embedded in LuaTeX.

Comment: there is some lua code to enable automatic long s here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/435638/why-i-do-not-have-%c5%bf-in-xetex-fontspec

Comment: I guess an alternative (albeit less desirable) to what I am asking for could be to replace the long ſ when typesetting in a contemporary Latin typeface. I.e. so that I'd still have to explicitly type the long ſ in my text, but when producing output without Fraktur, I'd get the round s in place of each long s.

Comment: Thanks @DavidCarlisle, I am going to try this and write up an answer, provided it works out.

Comment: Two remarks: First, I assume an automated solution for the s problem
is not possible as it requires semantic aspects (although one can
easily identify, for example, the end of a word with a virtual font
and the ligature mechanism). As you write a German text you might be
able to read German so see
https://www.bfds.de/wp-content/uploads/S-Regeln.pdf. Second, do not
letterspace ligatures like st in ``erster'' (and add more space after
a letterspaced word); see page 15 of
https://www.buchbinderei-koester.de/download/Knigge_digital.pdf.

Comment: @UdoWermuth Danke für die Anmerkungen! The letter-spacing of the st in "erster" is probably due to a lack of fine-tuning at this point. But thanks a lot for pointing it out and providing links to more detailed references.

Comment: actually i had a similar Problem a while ago and im really impressed you managed to produce the Long s without Problems (this is where i failed already, back then). if you would create a macro for the Long s this would not solve anything but you dont have to copy paste that character over and over again. also you could redefine the macro to be a normal s for use in a different font Setting.

Comment: @derbender both in Windows (look for MSKLC) and in Linux you can rather easily define (or redefine) your keyboard layouts. So no need to copy&paste. Simply type. Because of the visual similarity in blackletter my ſ is AltGr+f (on AltGr I already had ś assigned which I use for several languages other than my native).